# subprocess kills child processes but not the processes the child spawns

Tags: python, subprocess, selenium-grid

I have been having an issue whereby I can kill the processes that spawns the nodes but the nodes do not get killed. Does anyone have any suggest how I can do this?

Some of my latest failed attempts to accomplish this are:

```
node.terminate()
```

and

```
node.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
```

below is the code:

```
from subprocess import Popen
import json
import sys
import os
import signal
import requests

FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')

json_data = open('nodes.json', 'r').read()
data = json.loads(json_data)

port = data['port']

# launch hub
hub = Popen('java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar -role hub -port %s' % port, stdout=FNULL, stderr=FNULL, shell=True)

#launch nodes
nodes = []
for node in data['nodes']:
    options = ''
    if node['name'] == 'CHROME':
        options += '-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=../grid/chromedriver '
    #options += ' -browser browserName='+node['name']+' maxInstances='+str(node['maxInstances'])
    nodes.append(Popen('java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:%i/grid/register %s' % (port, options), stdout=FNULL, stderr=FNULL, shell=True))

# wait for user input
print "type 'q' and ENTER to close the grid:"
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if line == 'q\n':
        break

# close nodes
for node in nodes:
    #node.terminate()
    node.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)

# close hub   
r = requests.get('http://localhost:'+str(port)+'/lifecycle-manager?action=shutdown')
```

As far as im aware, I'm basically forced to use shell=True, to get redirections to work
Processing the child's stdout/stderr in the parent python process is not an option, since I couldn't find functionality for doing it in a non-waiting way (and the parent python process must do other things while the child is running)

```
# close nodes
for node in nodes:
    node.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
    node.terminate()
```

this seems to kill all the processes except for 1 of the nodes. Not always the same one

Comment: Try adding: ``node.wait()``

Comment: @JamesMills adding node.wait() just seems to stall the shutdown, pressumably due to the fact that the nodes are still active (thus its just keeps waiting for them to finish)

Comment: What if you don't set `shell=True`?

Comment: That's what I thought! Okay, I think you're only other option is to use ``node.terminate()`` which sends a ``SIGKILL`` signal. But I think you tried that already? Try in combination with ``node.wait()``

Comment: yea node.terminate() only kills the child not the grandchild. and using node.wait() in any combination causes it to stall

Comment: To wit: Invoking the shell gives you some arg-specifying conveniences, but it also means there's another process between the parent and child. The system shell may not be passing the SIGINT to its children.

Comment: I suspect @kojiro is right. I didn't notice you specifying ``shell=True`` in your code :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524937/how-to-send-a-signal-sigint-from-script-to-script-bash <-- this could be useful? Perhaps sending ``SIGTERM`` rather than ``SIGINT`` might work here?

Comment: SIGTERM and SIGINT seem to have the same effect.

Comment: What OS are you on? I tried to write up an experiment on this in OS X Mavericks and found that sending the same signal to the process did two or three different things depending on how I sent it. (Which seems _wrong_.)

Comment: @kojiro running ubuntu 12.04

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true might also be of use, it seems to cover similar situation (i.e. where use of shell=True is needed).

Comment: What process (the name) do you want to kill and which processes do you want to preserve? Could you create a [complete minimal code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (even with dummy subprocesses) to illustrate your point? It is not clear what processes do you want to kill: is it shell, is it `java`, or child processes started by jvm?

Comment: Here is a well-formed question and a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true

Answer (score 3):

You could try using `os.killpg`. This function sends the signal to the process group, it should work if your processes do not change process group.

```py
import os
import signal

os.killpg(os.getpgid(pid), signal.SIGINT)
```

Note, that process group will be changed if you are creating process under shell (bash, zsh, etc.), in that case more complicated technique should be used.

Comment: os.killpg(os.getpgid(pid), signal.SIGINT)

Comment: Unfortunately, this kills the calling program too. You'll need to add ``preexec_fn=os.setsid`` to ``Popen``.