# Sending SIGINT to foreground process works but not background

Tags: bash, signals, sigint, bash-trap

I have two scripts. *script1* spawns *script2* and then sends a `SIGINT` signal to it. However the trap in *script2* doesn't seem to work?!

script1:

```
#!/bin/bash
./script2 &
sleep 1
kill -SIGINT $!
sleep 2
```

script2:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "~~ENTRY"
trap 'echo you hit ctrl-c, waking up...' SIGINT
sleep infinity
echo "~~EXIT"
```

If change `./script2 &` to `./script2` and press `CTRL+C` the whole things works fine. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you are trying to achieve is that when `script2` receives the SIGINT it continues and prints the message. Then, you need

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "~~ENTRY"
trap 'echo you hit ctrl-c, waking up...; CONT=true' SIGINT
CONT=false
while ! $CONT
do
   sleep 1
done
echo "~~EXIT"
```

Comment: It is much cleaner to do `sleep inifinity& wait`

Comment: By putting the sleep in the background, the shell will trap the signal immediately.  (The sleep will continue running, and should be terminated in the trap.)

Comment: @WilliamPursell, as you mention `sleep/wait` can be used but I was assuming that something wants to be done while waiting

Comment: This doesn't work on my end. SIGINT is never caught by "./script2" and the trap message is never displayed, nor the "~~EXIT" message. "./script2" stays in memory and actually, this behavior seems consistent with bash documentation: background processes are NOT in the main process control group, and thus won't receive SIGINT by design. So, what did I miss ?

Answer (score 2):

You have several issues in your examples, at the end I have a solution for your issue:

- your first script seems to miss a `wait` statement, thus, it exits 
  after roughly 3 seconds. However `script2` will remain in memory and 
  running.

  How do you want bash to automatically figure which process it should 
  send the SIGINT signal ?
- Actually `bash` will disable `SIGINT` (and `SIGQUIT`) on background processes and they can't be enabled (you can check by running `trap` command alone to check the current status of set traps). See [How to send a signal SIGINT from script to script ? BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524937)

  So your `script2` is NOT setting a trap on `SIGINT` **because it's a background process**, both `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` are ignored and can't be anymore trapped nor resetted on background processes.

As a reference, here are the documentation from bash related to your issue:

Process group id effect on background process (in *Job Control* section of doc):

> [...] processes whose process group ID is equal to the current terminal
>   process group ID [..] receive keyboard-generated signals such as
>   SIGINT.  These processes are said  to  be  in the  foreground. 
>   **Background processes** are those whose process group ID  differs from
>   the terminal's; such processes **are immune to keyboard-generated
>   signals**.

Default handler for `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` (in *Signals* section of doc):

> Non-builtin commands run by bash have signal handlers set to the values inherited  by  the  shell  from its parent.  When job control is not in effect, **asynchronous commands ignore SIGINT and SIGQUIT** in addition to these  inherited handlers.

and about modification of traps (in `trap` builtin doc):

> **Signals  ignored upon entry to the shell cannot be trapped or reset**.

**SOLUTION 1**

modify your `script1` to be:

```
#!/bin/bash
{ ./script2; } &
sleep 1
subshell_pid=$!
pid=$(ps -ax -o ppid,pid --no-headers | sed -r 's/^ +//g;s/ +/ /g' |
                           grep "^$subshell_pid " | cut -f 2 -d " ")

kill -SIGINT $pid
sleep 2
wait      ## Don't forget this.
```

How does this work ? Actually, the usage of `{` and `}` will create a subshell, that will be limited by the explained limitation on `SIGINT`, because this subshell is a background process. However, the subshell's own subprocess are foreground and NOT background processes (for our subshell scope)... as a consequence, they can trap or reset `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` signals.

The trick is then to find the pid of this subprocess in the subshell, here I use `ps` to find the only process having the subshell's pid as parent pid.

**SOLUTION 2**

Actually, only direct new **process** managed as job will get their SIGINT and SIGQUIT ignored. A simple bash function won't. So if `script2` code was in a function sourced in `script1`, here would be your new `script1` that doesn't need anything else:

```
#!/bin/bash
script2() {
    ## script2 code
    echo "~~ENTRY"
    trap 'echo you hit ctrl-c, waking up...' SIGINT
    sleep infinity
    echo "~~EXIT"
}
## script1 code
script2 &
sleep 1
kill -SIGINT $!
sleep 2
```

This will work also. Behind the scene, the same mecanism than SOLUTION 1 is working: a bash function is very close to the `{` `}` construct.