# How to catch SIGINT within a Bash subshell

Tags: linux, bash, signals

If I run a command, such as grep, at the command line and hit ^C, the command is properly killed (with SIGINT I think).  And if I run the grep in background and then run a kill SIGINT on its PID, it similarly gets terminated.  **But** if I'm inside a script and run grep in background from the script, get its PID and then use 'kill -s SIGINT $PID', grep does not get killed.  Why?  If I use SIGTERM, instead of SIGINT, the kill *does* work.

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -rqa shazam /usr &
PID=$!
kill -s SIGINT $PID
```

Even if I put the grep in a subprocess, preceded by a SIGINT handler (in the subprocess), and hit the subprocess with SIGINT, the handler is not invoked.

```
#!/bin/bash
( trap 'echo "caught signal"' SIGINT; grep -rqa shazam /usr ) &
PID=$!
kill -s SIGINT $PID
```

The trap handler *is* invoked if I use SIGTERM, instead of SIGINT, but does not interrupt grep.  If I add '/bin/kill -s SIGTERM 0' to the trap handler, there is an indication that the grep process gets terminated, but grep has already completed its work by then.  I realize that Bash may have different default behaviors for the different signals, but I don't understand why my call to kill SIGINT is different than a ^C, why the trap call works for SIGTERM, but not for SIGINT, nor why SIGTERM isn't handled by the subprocess immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with further digging, I figured out 2 of my 3 questions.  When I backgrounded grep within the script, the shell told it to ignore SIGINT.  And Bash says it will wait to handle the signal until the subcommand is complete in some situations (which I don't fully follow at the moment), but the signal is handled immediately if hit the grep process directly with pkill.

Answer (score 0):

"Actually bash will disable SIGINT (and SIGQUIT) on background processes and they can't be enabled" [Background process and signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25511294/sending-sigint-to-foreground-process-works-but-not-background) [How SIGINT works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58473685/sending-sigint-to-forked-exec-process-which-runs-script-does-not-kill-it)

"Further background jobs are not supposed to be tied to the shell that started them. If you exit a shell, they will continue running. As such they shouldn't be interrupted by SIGINT, not by default. When job control is enabled, that is fulfilled automatically, since background jobs are running in separate process groups. When job control is disabled (generally in non-interactive shells), bash makes the asynchronous commands ignore SIGINT." [Independent Program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372541/why-doesnt-sigint-work-on-a-background-process-in-a-script)

[Reason why SIGTERM works](https://superuser.com/questions/865651/why-sigterm-signal-does-not-work-for-process-group)